# jQuery not reading variables on .ejs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, ejs

I'm using Express, and a Postgres database to load products onto an .ejs page with a `for..in` loop. The snippet that loads the products looks like this, and is pulling in the database info with templateVars:

```
            <script>
              let test;
            </script>

            <% for(let item in product) { %>

              <script>
                test += `<%- JSON.stringify(product[item]) %>`
              </script>

<div class="row" id="productList">
            <% for(let item in product) { %>
              <div class="card">
                <img src="<%= product[item].image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <h3 class="card-title">
                  <%= product[item].name %>
                </h3>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <%= product[item].description %>
                </p>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <p>
                    <%= product[item].price_cents %>
                  </p>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus add-burg-event"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% } %>
          </div>
```

I then want to use jQuery to add an event to the `add-burg-event` class. The jQuery I'm using looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("Document ready");
  $('.add-burg-event').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(test);
  });
});
```

The trouble with that is *all* the products in the `for..in` loop are now being returned in `test`, which I suppose makes sense. But how can I ensure that when I click the add to cart button (`.add-burg-event`), only *that* particular product is added to the variable, instead of adding each one from the loop?

I'm trying to use that product data to then update a cart, but am getting a large object with all the products, instead of just the one product that was clicked.

Comment: Use `e.target` to get the `<a>` tag, then using jQuery to get access to `.closest('.card')`.

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn I will take a look at those options in the docs!

Comment: All of the data that your cart needs (maybe also product id?) will have to be added to your HTML or Javascript, so that when a thing is clicked, Javascript can read those important fields from the browser in order to do some cart operation.

Comment: Looks very unorthodox. Use data attributes on the elements to pass your product id (or whatever else is needed) to. Not clear how the add to cart process works

Comment: Thank you @James Is the loop not sufficiently injecting that product data into the template? Or it needs to be added separately? And if it does, I'm a bit unsure about how to associate the product data with the card they are displayed on.

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl It is definitely an unusual set up. I had included the `test` variable just to test out what would happen. That will certainly be removed after it is working properly. I'm trying to avoid hard-coding each of the elements, but there is a disconnect when trying to associated the product data with the card, since each card is looped, it has the same id and classes

Comment: No unique identifiers on the items? Also concatenating the json that way makes it invalid object structure. What does it show in page?